# Group cascading in css

Tags: css

I wanted to know if there is a feature in CSS that I can use to group definitions in a certain cascade.

Normally in CSS I would do the following:

```
.class .inner1 {}
.class .inner2 {}
.class .inner3 {}
```

but is there a possiblity to do something like the following:

```
.class {
    .inner1 {}
    .inner2 {}
    .inner3 {}
}
```

I got inspired by the `@media`-queries that exist in CSS.

Comment: SASS preprocessor is an option to write your "group definitions".

Comment: This would require me to add an overhead to my css which I prefer not to have.

Answer (score 1):

Why using Sass or Less when you can do it easily with pure CSS?

```css
.class [class*="inner"] {
  color: red;
}

.inner1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.inner2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.inner3 {
  font-size: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <div class="inner1">CSS</div>
  <div class="inner2">WILD</div>
  <div class="inner3">CARD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.class .inner` as referenced by OP isn't the same as `.class.inner` as in your example. (Notice the space). And couldn't you simplify `div [class*="class"][class*="inner"]` into `.class[class*="inner"]`? Or simply `.class`?

Comment: This looks nice. How is this system called?

Comment: @MaxPlay CSS Wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with SCSS/SASS and/or LESS, which also offer other advantages like variables, mixins etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS preprocessors like SASS:

```
.class {
    .inner1 {}
    .inner2 {}
    .inner3 {}
}
```

will output

```
.class {}
.class .inner1 {}
.class .inner2 {}
.class .inner3 {}
```

You can continue to nest from .class → .inner1 → span ...etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in your `.css` source files then you'll have to use [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/) and a PostCSS plugin like [postcss-nested](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested).

Compiled CSS cannot currently contain nested selectors, but there is [a draft spec for css nesting](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/) so it may be possible in future.

Comment: Thank you. This draft looks very promising, exactly what I was looking for. I was interested in CSS, not SASS, LESS or any other plugin, because I knew this was possible in a plugin.

Comment: Coolio :) Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it has helped you. Cheers.